# Getting "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented" when adding new columns to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pivot table which contains n number of columns with a format of YYYY-WW, since not all year-week combinations are present, I need to calculate the price difference and percentage of a weeks price vs the previous week.

I got it figured out, and it's working, but I get the following error:

```py
/var/folders/b6/jndhzshn3hlbwyrdsjzj2znw0000gn/T/ipykernel_28918/446450422.py:38: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df_pivot[f"% {year} [{week:02d}-{prev_week:02d}]"] = (df_pivot[current_week_colname] / df_pivot[prev_week_colname]) - 1
/var/folders/b6/jndhzshn3hlbwyrdsjzj2znw0000gn/T/ipykernel_28918/446450422.py:37: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df_pivot[f"$ {year} [{week:02d}-{prev_week:02d}]"] = df_pivot[current_week_colname] - df_pivot[prev_week_colname]
/var/folders/b6/jndhzshn3hlbwyrdsjzj2znw0000gn/T/ipykernel_28918/446450422.py:38: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df_pivot[f"% {year} [{week:02d}-{prev_week:02d}]"] = (df_pivot[current_week_colname] / df_pivot[prev_week_colname]) - 1
```

This is the code I'm running:

```py
...
years = ["2020", "2021", "2022"]
df_pivot_colnames = tuple(df_pivot.columns)
...
for year in years:
    for week in range(2, 53):
        prev_week = week - 1

        current_week_colname = f"{year}-{week:02d}"
        prev_week_colname = f"{year}-{prev_week:02d}"
        new_week_colname = f"{year} [{week:02d}-{prev_week:02d}]"

        if (
            current_week_colname in df_pivot_colnames
            and prev_week_colname in df_pivot_colnames
        ):
            df_pivot[f"$ {new_week_colname}"] = (
                df_pivot[current_week_colname] - df_pivot[prev_week_colname]
            )
            df_pivot[f"% {new_week_colname}"] = (
                df_pivot[current_week_colname] / df_pivot[prev_week_colname]
            ) - 1

df_pivot.to_csv(source_csv_path + "output_" + csv)
```

I understand the message, but I am not sure how I could incorporate `concat`, having in mind that the column name will change depending on the `df` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the new columns to a dictionary and, after the for-loop, concat `df_pivot` with a dataframe instantiated from said dictionary:

```py
import pandas

years = ["2020", "2021", "2022"]
df_pivot_colnames = tuple(df_pivot.columns)

new_columns = {}

for year in years:
    for week in range(2, 53):
        prev_week = week - 1

        current_week_colname = f"{year}-{week:02d}"
        prev_week_colname = f"{year}-{prev_week:02d}"
        new_week_colname = f"{year} [{week:02d}-{prev_week:02d}]"

        if (
            current_week_colname in df_pivot_colnames
            and prev_week_colname in df_pivot_colnames
        ):
            new_columns[f"$ {new_week_colname}"] = (
                df_pivot[current_week_colname] - df_pivot[prev_week_colname]
            )
            new_columns[f"% {new_week_colname}"] = (
                df_pivot[current_week_colname] / df_pivot[prev_week_colname]
            ) - 1

df_pivot = pd.concat([df_pivot, pd.DataFrame(new_columns)], axis=1)
```